# Check to see if Facebook post exists

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app (or link really) that allows my customer to share a certain product to their wall/timeline through this protocol:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP_ID&link=....

Upon successful share, the customer gets a coupon code, once he/she is directed back to my site.

I'd like to be able to verify the existence of the share post to determine if the rebate code is valid or not. I have the post id, looking like this:

704745000_513399762010000 (random example)

I kind of figured out that I need permission to query for a specific post using graph-api in a users timeline, but how can I get the permission? Any pointers and examples (in php) are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php sdk to both: create the post, get a returned id to store in database and authenticate user to your application.

there is a login and api request sample included in the sdk.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: Great, thanks for the pointer. :) So instead of using the dialog/feed gateway I should use the API to post for the user, correct? And then I can also query for the existance of the post? I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

FYI:

> I'd like to be able to verify the existence of the share post to determine if the rebate code is valid or not

That sounds like you’re violating Platform Policies, [IV. Application Integration Points](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration):

> 1. You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.

Comment: You can reward a user though correct?  asper https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Rewarding_Users/

Comment: Yes – but not directly for making a post/share.

Comment: @ShawnECarter, CBroe is correct...this is also mentioned in the supplemental material section (see update above)